# Blackberry app exiting without crashing

Tags: blackberry

I'm doing a Blackberry application and although on the emulator all runs fine, when I switch from one screen to another and then back to the previous one. The strange thing is that the application doesn't crash, it simply exits... The console says the following:

```
[0.0] AM: Exit MYAPP(308)
[0.0] ApplicationManagerImpl.processExited : process process switching to background:  pid=308
[0.0] AM: Foreground is requested: net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(130)
[0.0] Process MYAPP(308) cleanup started
[0.0] Process MYAPP(308) cleanup done
[0.0] AM: Foreground is set: net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(130)
```

What could be the issue? Is there some sort of garbage collector on blackberry that is exiting my application? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Just remember that BB app will be automatically closed whenever you close last `Screen`

Comment: Yeah, but that would show on the console that the app lost focus because it has no screens.

Comment: Well for some reason that didn't show up on the console this time. I was doing screen popping and then pushing, instead of the reverse, causing the application to momentaniously lose screens and exiting. This only happened on a real device, on the emulator all worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for some reason that didn't show up on the console this time. I was doing screen popping and then pushing, instead of the reverse, causing the application to momentaniously lose screens and exiting. This only happened on a real device, on the emulator all worked fine.